# What is the best solution for htaccess caching

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, webserver

I have found a number of articles such as [this one](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html) that talk about using htaccess to cache images and files on your webserver.

But which is **best**, **why**, and what is the best **implementation** of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometime ago, I wrote my own personal take on this subject. I've written two blog posts about it, and give some hints and tips about what I've used to get the best out of caching and compression. here's the links:

1. [Apache 101 cache control](http://www.placona.co.uk/126/vps/apache-101-cache-control)
2. [Apache 101 compressing files](http://www.placona.co.uk/124/vps/apache-101-compressing-files/)

I love this subject by the way, so you're more than welcome to ask any more questions :-)

Hope they help you

Comment: I've disabled most of it die to an experience I;m doing with CDN's :-)

Comment: I can't see much cdn requests on your page. Just usual conditional get requests, served by apache by default.

Comment: And here's the downside to link-only answers: when a link expires, the answer gets useless. :(

Comment: The links have been fixed

Answer (score -1):

The best way is to leave the things alone and let the web server to handle this.
Not every article is worth to read.

Comment: Adding compression and cache control rules to your site can seriously speed it up.  This results in better user experience, less bandwidth used, and possibly even better search engine rankings.  See the Google Speed pages for more information.